# Make a system call in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to execute a python or a java class from inside dart.

The following is a snippet which I have used from a stackoverflow question Java

```java
Runtime currentRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process executeProcess = currentRuntime.exec("cmd /c c:\\somepath\\pythonprogram.py");
```

I would like to know how to make such calls in dart.

Basically I have a UI where in the user uploads  code in java and python.I want to execute the uploaded code from the dart environment instead of creating a routine in java or python on the folder where the code is uploaded.

I personally dont know if this is possible, since dart is purely in a VM.

I want to execute the following command

```
java abc
```

from inside dart.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can simply use [Process.run](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/Process.html#run).

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  Process.run('java', ['abd']);
}
```

You can also access to `stdout`, `stderr` and `exitCode` through the resulting [ProcessResult](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/ProcessResult.html) :

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  Process.run('java', ['abd']).then((ProcessResult pr){
    print(pr.exitCode);
    print(pr.stdout);
    print(pr.stderr);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can I get any flag or any message as to whether the execution was successful or not.I actually don't need the output but I do need to make sure that the code executed properly without any runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks that process.run does most of the things I wanted.Will try the updated code