# System call in dart denied due to Permissions

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making a flutter app (flutter uses dart) and would like to use a python script I wrote. This is because some of the python libraries are very helpful in my use case. While researching if running a python script was possible, I discovered I could make a system call like so:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  Process.run('python', ['getLink.py']);
}
```

I therefore placed all the files getLink.py needed and getLink.py in the folder this is running from but got the following error: "ProcessException: Permission denied". I tried giving the full Path as well, but this didn't work either. My question is: Why is the call being denied permission to execute this file?

Some sources I looked at:

[Make a system call in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347483/make-a-system-call-in-dart)

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Process/run.html

Comment: In which directory is this script stored? How do you run this script? Do you want to run this code on the phone or only for project task automation?

Comment: It is stored in my project directory (so the same place as pubspec.yaml). I would like to run this on the phone later using the python interpreter. (Not for project task automation)

Comment: I don't think the directory that contains `pubspec.yaml` is a good idea. It should be in `test/`, `tool/`, `example/`, or for plain Dart projects `bin/` or `web/`. That according to the Pub package layout convention. I'd try to pass `runInShell: true` to `run('python', [...], runInShell: true)`. Not sure this helps but worth a try for debug purposes to see what happens.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows for development

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be `python.exe` instead of `python`

Comment: So I put the files in the /test directory and made the command this: Process.run('python', ['getNew.py'], runInShell: true), but it still gave me the same error. Should I be supplying a path somewhere?

Comment: Run it with `dart test/my_dart_script.dart`

Comment: I tried python.exe but no luck :(. Is it maybe only possible for testing automation purposes?

Comment: Do you mean from the command line? (I tried, but it says dart isn't recognized)

Comment: Executing a process from a Dart script started from a shell like you are trying is not special at all and should just work.  `Process.run('getLink.py', runInShell: true);` might be worth a try.

Comment: If `dart` isn't recognized, then this is an issue with your Dart setup. Either you didn't install the standalone Dart SDK or you didn't set a path to its `bin` directory. The Flutter SDK also contains a `dart` executable but I would not suggest using this one. It might have some peculiarities when running Dart scripts from shell like that.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here... are you wanting your Flutter app to execute a Python script *on your phone* while it is running? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want my flutter app to execute the python script on a mobile device while it's running

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Being able to run any executable on a device would have security issues, thus why you get the permission denied message. Even if there weren't security issues, does Android even have a Python interpreter built in? `Process.run` is more for Dart applications that are running on Windows/Mac/Linux environments.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter doesn't seem to be able to compile and run python scripts natively using `Process.run()` on mobile devices. You might need to use plugins to help you with that. I see that [starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut) plugin should help do the job, but it's been a while since it has been last updated and it has yet to have support for null-safety.